# Change script and image URLs without doubling effect

Tags: html, regex, url

i've created a small php script to take cookies from mysql db and then login to a specific site with that cookie and return the page to the user (it is like the web proxy scripts but with pre-defined cookies )

let's assume that the site that i'm trying to access via that cookie is http://www.example.com

what i'm trying to do is to change all the html elements that has relative paths to the actual path like this

```
 <img src="images/top.jpg">
```

it becomes

```
 <img src="http://www.example.com/images/top.jpg">
```

and the same for all css and scripts element.

it's easy to do by using regex but the problem is that you'll change the element that doesn't have relative path

```
<img src="http://www.example.comhttp://www.example.com/images/top.jpg">
```

so what i'm asking for is some way to change the relative paths without affecting other real path

Comment: Very poorly formatted and explained question. See [**How do I ask a good question?**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @FrankConijn ok, i read it what should i do now i don't think my question has anything wrong

Comment: Think again: one long paragraph, no punctuation/capitalization/separate sentences, no code, no demo, and a blurry story about what your problem is - which I still don't understand, even after heaving read it three times.

Comment: @FrankConijn thanks, you made your point.

Comment: Good edit! But you should remove the `php` and `dom` tags, because it is not a question specifically related to them. Regarding your question: have you considered using the simple [**HTML base tag**](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp)? I'm not sure though whether that gives a doubling effect as well. You would have to check that for yourself. But if it doesn't, it might save you time and effort.

Comment: @FrankConijn that solved the problem but it has conflict with another regex,i guss i'll continue trying, anyway that was really helpful thank u.